# Fedora 26 on USB stick updated kernel 4.11.8 to 4.11.9 no longer boots

Tags: fedora, kernel, boot, upgrade

I installed Fedora 26 alpha some time ago on a USB stick and been using it ever since. Everything worked fine, until I updated to 4.11.9 and the PC would not boot, saying /dev/mapper/fedora-root does not exist.
I have not changed my hardware in any way, and it still boots fine with the 2 older kernels 4.11.8 and 4.11.7
I tried:
sudo dracut -fv /boot/initramfs-4.11.9-300.fc26.x86_64.img 4.11.9-300.fc26.x86_64
But it still won't boot.

Later removed the 4.11.9 kernel and run upgrade to install the new 4.11.10 and now the new 4.11.11, but still get the same error.
So I'm still stuck with booting into my old kernel.

Comment: The 4.11.11 kernel works for me fine on my laptotp. You should probably specify what is your hardware, if you want some help.

Comment: I am using an Asus k53sv laptop.